# C-file use a variable from makefile to c-file

Tags: c, variables, makefile

How can a c-file use variables from a c-file?

makefile:

```
VARIABLE=$(shell grep textfile.txt | -c 66)
```

c-file pseudo code:

```
VARIABLE2 = VARIABLE;
```

Comment: So, what, you want to use macros to define which variable names get assigned to/from? That seems a lot less than ideal... What is the specific problem you're trying to solve? There is quite possibly a much better way.

Comment: Good question. The task is that a textfile is containing information the the whole repo is depended on (for example partnumber). This information I want to "hand out" to the C-funktion via the makefile. The reason for the C-funtions to not go directly to the textfile and get the information is that the makefile in it self also need the information. Thus, it's better that all C-files get the info from the makefile and the the connection to the textfile is only between makefile-textfile.

Comment: I understand that. I wasn't asking what you're doing *generally*. I was asking why, *specifically*, the data you're passing from the Makefile to the C sources are the names of variables. Or was that just a bad example?

Comment: The reason is that I have a got different git repos for different products. All products have partnumbers, version number and more. In every repo, the info os used by a lot of c-files, python-files and more. Today everything is hardcoded which means that, when you want to update the partno for a product, you must commit like 10 files with the same info. Solution: save a textfile in every repo with partno info and let all other files in the repo get info from that text file.

Comment: Note that they invented these gadgets called 'databases' to help store data that must be accessed by multiple applications.  What you describe is a disaster in the making (CM or VCS busy-work at best; inconsistent data is more likely the problem).

Answer (score 1):

Usually by creating a macro passed to the C compiler, perhaps using some variation on the theme of:

```
CFLAGS += -DVARIABLE2="${VARIABLE}"
```

You have to worry about whether there are quotes etc in the value of the Make variable (I'm not familiar with the `-c` command shown in `VARIABLE=$(shell grep textfile.txt | -c 66)`).

Comment: The command -c is not important for the question. It is a regular expression for the grep-function saying "take character/bit/int/or other number 66 from textfile.txt."

I will try to do the variable as a macro and come back with feedback.

Comment: I guess that The -D option sets pre-processor variables which mean that my C-file can look like my pseudo code and that I need to call the c-file with gcc $(VARIABLE") myCFile.c. Without the macro in the gcc-call t will not work.

Comment: Also, If I call several c-files (c1.c  c2.c c3.c) but c1.c is the only one using the variable, it guess it's ok to also call the other c-files that don't use the variable as "gcc $(VARIABLE") c2.c".

Comment: In general terms, yes (to both questions).  With GNU Make, you could use: `file1.o: CFLAGS += -DVARIABLE2="${VARIABLE}"` to add the definition to CFLAGS only while compiling `file1.o` (from `file1.c`, or whatever).